# How to find and save in a variable only number in txt file

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a text file which has the following content (only 1 line). The second number is the Process id. I just want to read this and just need the PID in a variable in windows command file. How can i do this?

Server_exec.exe         25536

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FOR` loop to parse the line and get the value.

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %A IN ('TYPE "C:\src\t\so70987339.txt"') DO (SET "THENUM=%A")
ECHO THENUM is %THENUM%
```